# Why jQuery has to receive 2 objects: body & html when scrolling whole page with animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, scrolltop

In all the tutorials I found around the web on animating scrolling of the page with jQuery, I found that most of them are using the following code to do that:

```
$("html, body").animate(....
```

I was trying to find out why it's needed to animate 2 objects: html and body, but not luck.
I might think it's needed to cover all major browsers… But why really, **can someone explain please?**

Answer (score 1):

chrome/safari uses html to animate, while firefox uses body (might be the other way around, don't remember!)

You could just use $(window).animate.

Comment: Also, older versions of Opera would animate both! Here is an [article](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/01/18/jquery-smooth-scroll-bugs.html) explaining it as well as a fix.