# jQuery scrollTo

Tags: jquery, html, scrollto

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contact_menu").click(function() {
        $(body).scrollTo("#contact", 800);  
    }); 
});
```

I typed this in my code, hoped it would make my page scroll, but I won't work. I tried several ways, but I can't get it right.

I hope one of you can help me.

Comment: Can you post your html?

Comment: sure it coming right away

Comment: What's $(body)? Maybe you meant $('body')?

Comment: yes of course, doesn't solve the problem though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#contact_menu").click(function() {
        $("body").animate({
         scrollTop: $("#contact").offset().top
     }, 2000);
});
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/43umh/

Were you trying this plugin? http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Comment: Yes I was trying that, but wasn't sure wether it was a plugin or not.

Comment: @Johan - A good way to find out is to google "_jquery scrollto_".  If the function does not need a plugin, the first result will take you right to the jQuery documentation.  If a plugin is required, the first few search results should make it obvious.  In general, whenever you have a question about a function, you should immediately google "_jquery FUNCTION_NAME_".

Comment: I think Firefox requires you to animate `$("html")`.  That's why most tutorials on animated scrolling have `$("html, body")` as the object to animate. ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769630/why-jquery-has-to-receive-2-objects-body-html-when-scrolling-whole-page-with

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use jQuery to scroll to something, use `.scrollTop`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pos = $('#contact').position();
    $("#contact_menu").click(function() {
        $(body).animate({scrollTop:pos.top},800);  
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#contact_menu").click(function() {
        $('body, html').animate({ scrollTop: $("#contact").offset().top }, 800);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know  about the "scrollTo" function, but if this actually exists, the problem could be in the selector.  Depending on the browser, you either have to animate the body OR the html object.  What i usually do to ANIMATE the scrollTop is something like this:

```
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#contact').position().top+'px'}, 400, function() {})
```

Note that i chose 400ms for the duration, but you can use whatever you want.  The last "function()" param is the callback, which means it is called right when the animation is done. Hope this helped.

Comment: yes you're right, scrollTo doesn't exist, or it doesn't anymore maybe but it's solved with the answer of Hanlet

Comment: @Johan - _scrollTo()_ requires [a plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo).  _scrollTop()_ does not.

Comment: And .scrollTop() doesn't animate, .animate({scrollTop : value}) does!